# I need to convert codeigniter with mongodb to codeigniter and pdo or mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pdo

I have one project that is made in codeigniter and mongodb ... I need that project to be converted to codeigniter with pdo or mysqli. it is working with mongodb but i am not getting which files should be replace or what configuration needs to be reverted.
Can someone help regarding file structures
Thanks
Regards

Comment: Have you tried doing this yourself before posting?

Comment: yes a lot but no luck when i tried to replace config.php file and delete mongodb,php file it is giving error No mongodb.php file found

Comment: to start with: set in application/config/database.php the new default driver:  `$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysqli";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the config/Database.php and select the 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli' and make the relevant connection change like hostname, username, database, etc